# Setting transparency of layer group with Python in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, transparency-opacity

How can I set the transparency for all layers within a group of layers?

I assume this will require the use of a FOR loop in the Python Console.

Based on [How to set the transparency for multiple layers or add a global transparancy preference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88908/how-to-set-the-transparency-for-multiple-layers-or-add-a-global-transparancy-pre)

I tried the following:

```
for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
   layer.renderer().setOpacity(0.5)
```

But I only get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'renderer'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'QgsVectorLayer' objects have not attribute 'renderer'. The equivalent method is `layer.setLayerTransparency(50)`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that 'QgsVectorLayer' objects have not attribute 'renderer'. This kind of method is for raster layers. If you want to change the transparency of **QgsVectorLayer** objects you have to use the method: 'setLayerTransparency(int)'; located in **QgsVectorLayer** class.

Next code works for these kind of objects:

```
mc=iface.mapCanvas()

layers=[]

n = mc.layerCount()

for i in range(n):
    layers.append(mc.layer(i))

for layer in layers:

    if layer.type() == 0: #QgsVectorLayer
        layer.setLayerTransparency(95)

    else:
        layer.renderer().setOpacity(0.5)

    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I tested it in QGIS. See next images (raster layer has a different projection but the transparency was also assigned):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your example is setting transparency on many layers but not on many layers within a group.

Comment: This no longer works in QGIS 3.XX

Comment: The link above from @joskal is no longer valid, FYI.

Answer (score 5):

As of QGIS 3.XX the given answers don't work. Also there is no mention of `opacity` or `transparency` in the documentation of `QgsVectorLayer`.

According to API break: https://qgis.org/api/3.0/api_break.html
this is what works in QGIS 3.XX:

```
vlayer.setOpacity(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For qgis 3.x you may use the plugin "[Group Transparency](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/group_transparency/)"