# Changing style across multiple layers

Tags: qgis, style

I've loaded several shapefiles into QGIS and I'd like to increase the transparency across all of those layers while keeping them their original color.  Can this be done without changing each layer individually?

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88908/how-to-set-the-transparency-for-multiple-layers-or-add-a-global-transparancy-pre