# "AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'legendInterface'" in PyQGIS 3

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console, interface

The following piece of code works well in QGIS 2, however, it does not work in QGIS 3.

```py
myDir = 'd:/work/output_folder/'

layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()

for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider = layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   opts = ["COMPRESS=LZW"] 
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + layer.name() + ".tif")
   file_writer.setCreateOptions(opts)
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, extent, layer.crs())
```

This is the error I get when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'legendInterface'
```

Does someone know what has replaced `legendInterface` in the new version or what other changes I might have to make to get this to run in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could just replace

```py
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
```

with

```py
layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
```

Comment: This solution did not work well enough for me as the obtained layers were not in the same order as listed in Layers Panel.

Comment: @AleksMat - Good to know that you found a method for your problem :)

Answer (score 11):

The equivalent of

```py
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
```

in QGIS 3 is

```py
layers = [tree_layer.layer() for tree_layer in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()]
```

This recursively finds all layers and returns them in the same order as listed in Layers Panel.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html - there are literally thousands of changes to the API, which scripts need to be upgraded to handle.

> `QgsLegendInterface` was removed. It was replaced by layer tree API
> ([`QgsLayerTreeNode`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html) class and others). Methods that deal with custom
> actions in main window's layer tree context menu were moved to
> [`QgisInterface`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html):
>
> - `addLegendLayerAction()` moved to
>   [`QgisInterface::addCustomActionForLayerType()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a2e1394521d90f15fbddb0ce875520460)
> - `addLegendLayerActionForLayer()` moved to
>   [`QgisInterface::addCustomActionForLayer()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#afd2ba088d6a9ec9a7196d19c1b92c57a)
> - `removeLegendLayerAction()`
>   moved to [`QgisInterface::removeCustomActionForLayerType()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ade0f6018f58a664c5acf713089bf16b4)

Answer (score 4):

I found this to list layers:

```py
layers = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrder()
```